# parametric integral relating to hyperbolic function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Suppose that $a$ is real number such that $0<a<1$, how can we calculate
$$ I(a)=\int_0^\infty \big(1-\frac{\tanh ax}{\tanh x}\big)dx .$$
As for some speical cases, I can work out $I(1/2)=1$.  Any suggestion to the integral above? Tks.

Comment: Letting $t=e^{x/n}$, for rational values of $a=\dfrac mn$, the integrand becomes a rational function in *t*, which can be solved using partial fractions.

Comment: For general $a$, this seems to be expressible in terms of the so-called quantum dilogarithm functions.

Comment: @O.L.: Well, can you provide with me some references if possible?

Comment: I know only a few physics papers, but maybe you can trace the relevant mathematical literature from this starting point. Look e.g. at the integral representation of the function $S_b(x)$ on p.25 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0301193.pdf). Rescaling the integration variable, your expression can be written as something like $\partial_{x_1}\ln S_b(x_1)- \partial_{x_2} \ln S_b(x_2)$ with suitably chosen $x_1, x_2$ and $b$.

Comment: [This thesis](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~vdbult/Thesis.pdf) may be of some help as well. Here the relevant function is called hyperbolic gamma function, cf integral representation (2.2.2).

Answer (score 5):

Expanding @Lucian's comment, if $a=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I(a)&=&q\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{\tanh px}{\tanh qx}\right)\,dx=q\int_{1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^{2p}-1}{x^{2p}+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2q}+1}{x^{2q}-1}\right)\frac{dx}{x}\\&=&2q\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2q}-x^{2p}}{(x^{2p}+1)(x^{2q}-1)}\cdot\frac{dx}{x}=q\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2p}-x^{2q}}{(1+x^{2q})(1-x^{2p})}\cdot\frac{dx}{x}\\&=&\pi i q\sum_{z\in Z\cap \{\Im z>0\}}\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{x^{2p}-x^{2q}}{x(1+x^{2q})(1-x^{2p})},x=z\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $$Z=Z_p\cup Z_q=\left\{e^{\frac{\pi i}{p}},e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}},\ldots,e^{\frac{(p-1)\pi i}{p}}\right\}\cup\left\{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4q}},e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4q}},\ldots,e^{\frac{(2q-1)\pi i}{4q}}\right\}.$$
However, I strongly doubt that a nice closed formula exists, since, for instance:
$$I(3/5)=\frac{\pi}{15} \sqrt{\frac{154}{3}+\frac{18}{\sqrt{5}}-4 \sqrt{30 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}}.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. Residue theorm is really a powerful tool. Can we get a closed form of the integral?

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in particular cases:

$$\begin{align}
I\left( \frac15 \right) & = \sqrt{2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} \, \, \pi \\
I\left( \frac14 \right) & = \frac{\pi}{2} + 1 \\
I\left( \frac13 \right) & = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \, \pi \\
I\left( \frac25 \right) & = \left(\sqrt{2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} - \frac54 \right) \pi \\
I\left( \frac12 \right) & = 1 \\
I\left( \frac35 \right) & = \frac{10\pi}{3\sqrt3} + \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt5}} \, \pi- \sqrt{5+2\sqrt5} \, \pi \\
I\left( \frac23 \right) & = \frac{3\pi}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3} \, \pi}{3} \\
I\left( \frac34 \right) & = \frac{8\sqrt{3} \,\pi}{27} - \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac13 \\
\end{align}$$

There are also some closed-form for $a \geq 1$:

$$\begin{align}
I(1) & = 0 \\
I(2) & = -\frac{\pi}{4} \\
I(3) & = -\frac{2\sqrt{3} \, \pi}{9} \\
I(4) & = -\frac{\sqrt{2} \, \pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{8} \\
I(5) & = -\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{1+ \frac{2}{\sqrt5}} \, \pi \\
I(6) & = -\frac{5 \pi}{12} - \frac{\sqrt{3} \, \pi}{9}
\end{align}$$

I've got them by using CAS and some manual simplification.

---

@spanferkel

$$\begin{align}
I\left(\frac 45 \right) & = -\frac{1}{40} \left(25+48 \sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{5}}-2 \sqrt{2050-352 \sqrt{5}-400 \sqrt{25-11 \sqrt{5}}}\right) \pi \\
I\left(\frac 16 \right) & = \frac{5 \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}}+1
\end{align}$$

The expressions are simplifications of sums with $\arctan$ terms.

---

@spanferkel

$$\begin{align}
I\left( \frac 18 \right) & = 1+\sqrt{2}\,\pi \\
I\left( \frac 28 \right) & = \frac{\pi}{2} +1\\
I\left( \frac 38 \right) & = -{\frac {16}{27}}\,\sqrt {3}\,\pi+\sqrt {2}\,\pi+\frac 13 \\
I\left( \frac 48 \right) & = 1\\
I\left( \frac 58 \right) & = -\sqrt {2}\,\pi +{\frac {32}{125}}\,\sqrt {25+10\,\sqrt {5}}\,\pi -{\frac {16}{125}}\,\sqrt {25-10\,\sqrt {5}}\,\pi+\frac 15 \\
I\left( \frac 68 \right) & = {\frac {8}{27}}\,\sqrt {3}\,\pi -\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac 13
\end{align}$$

I couldn't find a closed-form of $I(7/8)$. The expressions are coming again from sums in term of $\arctan$.

Comment: However, $I(\dfrac35)$ simplifies to $\left(-2\sqrt{\dfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}}+\dfrac{10}9\sqrt{3}\right)\pi=\left( -\sqrt  {2+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}+\dfrac{10}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\pi$, somewhat related to $I(\dfrac25)$. Knowing that $\sin(\pi/5)= \sqrt{\dfrac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}}$ etc., there might be some hope for a general closed form expression. Can your CAS provide $I(\dfrac45)$ and $I(\dfrac16)$? On the other hand, it is really funny and unusual that for $q=4$, algebraic multiples of $\pi$ are "mixed" with rationals. I suppose, for $q=8$ as well?

Comment: @spanferkel $q=4$ means $a=4$?

Comment: no, I meant the denominator of $\dfrac14,\dfrac24=\dfrac12,\dfrac34$.

Comment: Thank you for the two values. Note again that more simply, 

$I\left(\dfrac 45 \right)   = -\dfrac{1}{40} \left(25-2 \sqrt{10}\sqrt{ 205+16 \sqrt{5}-40 \sqrt{5 (5+\sqrt{5})} }\right)$. And as a working hypothesis: for even denominators, there is a $\pi $ part and an algebraic (or even rational?!) part. Maybe the latter one exhibits a simple pattern, that would be a start. (Considering many more values, of course...) :)

Comment: The 2 middle terms of $I\left( \dfrac 58 \right)$ simplify to ${\dfrac {16}{125}}\,\sqrt {5(25+2\,\sqrt {5})}\,\pi$, but again that is no more a power of $\sqrt{\phi}$ :( Can you give your arctan expression for 7/8? It might have $\dfrac17$ as rational part.  Infact, so far for p/q with odd p and even q, the rational part is each time just 1/p.

Comment: @spanferkel You could find a closed-form of $I(7/8)$ [here](http://mathb.in/22199?key=8dabe39ab532f632f9b9dc11246a7fef5a928a78).

Comment: Thank you. I see... It contains several sums of 7th roots of unity that vanish, e.g. the denominator is just $686=2\cdot7^3$, but the factor of $\pi$ is  $343+256\left(8\cos(\pi/14)-3\cos(3\pi/14)+5\cos(5\pi/14)\right)$, which does not simplify more. :( What a pity!

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible close-form in the website \${http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic482.html}$.

His result shows that
$$ -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Big(_k^{-2}\Big)\frac{\psi\big(a(k+1)\big)}{k+1}-\frac{2\ln 2}{a}-2\gamma.$$
Right? we can check it whatever.