# Another parametric integral relating to hyperbolic function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

if $0<a\leq1$, then canwe get a closed form of 
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{\tanh x}\frac{1}{\cosh^2(ax)}dx.$$
In fact,if $a=1$,$I(a=1)=\pi^2/8$.

Comment: This is related to the derivative with respect to $a$ of your other integral (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938664/parametric-integral-relating-to-hyperbolic-function/938717#938717).

Comment: Year, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in particular cases:
$$\begin{align}
I\left(\frac14\right) & = \pi^2 + 2 \\
I\left(\frac13\right) & = -12\operatorname{Li}_2\left( \frac{2}{i\sqrt{3}-1} \right) -12\operatorname{Li}_2\left( -\frac{2}{i\sqrt{3}+1} \right) - \frac{5\pi^2}{8} \\
I\left(\frac12\right) & = \frac{\pi^2}{4} + 1 \\
I\left(\frac34\right) & = -\frac{13\pi^2}{243} + \frac{32\pi\sqrt{3}}{81} + \frac29\\
I\left(1\right) & = \frac{\pi^2}{8} \\
\end{align}$$

There are also some closed-form for $a>1$:

$$\begin{align}
I\left(2\right) & = \frac{3\pi^2}{32} - \frac{\pi}{8}  \\
I\left(3\right) & = \frac{49\pi^2}{648} - \frac{2\pi \sqrt{3}}{27}
\end{align}$$

I've got them by using CAS and some manual simplification.