# A mysterious limit related to the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{\tanh(ax)}{\tanh x}\right)\,dx$

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

I have to show that the following limit:
$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\Big[\sin(\pi a)\int_0^\infty \left(1-\frac{\tanh ax}{\tanh x}\right)dx\Big]=\pi\ln2$$
holds.

This problem relates to my previous question [parametric integral relating to hyperbolic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938664/parametric-integral-relating-to-hyperbolic-function).

Comment: You seem to be missing a question here.....The statement is "suppose equation x holds".   Then...what?

Comment: You will obviously have to apply l'Hopital, which will imply differentiating under the integral sign.

Comment: @Alan: Show that $\cdots$.

Comment: @Roger209 Much better :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{\tanh(x/n)}{\tanh(x)}\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{e^{2x/n}-1}{e^{2x/n}+1}\cdot\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\right)\,dx$$
hence:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{x}-e^{x/n}}{(e^{x/n}+1)(e^{x}-1)}\,dx=n\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n-z}{z(z+1)(z^n-1)}\,dz=n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{n-1}-1}{z^n-1}\frac{dz}{z+1}$$

If we consider the sequence of functions given by $f_n=\frac{z^{n-1}-1}{z^n-1}$, we have that $f_n\to 1$ pointwise on $[0,1)$, hence:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{n-1}-1}{z^n-1}\frac{dz}{z+1}\to \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x+1}=\log 2$$
holds by the dominated convergence theorem and it is enough to prove our claim, since $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\sin(a)}{a}=1.$ We can also avoid the dominated convergence theorem by estimating how much $f_n$ deviates from $1$ on $[0,1)$:
$$ 1-f_n(z) = \frac{1-z}{1-z^n}z^{n-1}\leq z^{n-1}$$
then applying a trivial inequality:
$$ \log 2-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f_n(z)\,dz}{z+1}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{n-1}}{z+1}\,dz\leq\int_{0}^{1}z^{n-1}\,dz = \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Very nice and simple solution.

Comment: nice work @jack

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: The idea here is rather good, but there may exists an error. I don't think the last integral of the first line is equal to the first integral of the second line. That means, the two integrals, before and after the word "Hence", are not equal. Anyway, your result is right.

Comment: @Roger209: they are, you can check it numerically if you want. There is just a change of variable bringing $2x$ into $x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Yes, I'am sorry, but I just made a mistake. I thought you use the identity "$\exp{2x}-1=(\exp{x}+1)(\exp{x}-1)$" initially.